# SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: jquery, unexpected-token

the code worked until line 48, after which it no longer worked. I would like to implement the switch on the "move" button on line 50-62, but this gave me the error Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
  <title>Prova Jquery</title>
  <!-- Fogli di stile -->
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <body>

  <div class="container" id="effetti">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur</p>

   <a href="https://www.google.it/">vai su google</a> 
   <button type="button "id="nascondi-immagine">Nascondi </button> 
   <button type="button" id="mostra-immagine">Mostra </button>   
   <button type="button" id="sposta-immagine">Sposta </button>   


   <p><img src="blu.jpg" \></p>




  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

file 1.js :

```
$(function(){
  $("#effetti")
    .fadeIn(12000);//effetto opacita in 12 secondi 

  $("#effetti")//sul DIV che si chiama effetti
    .on({ //permette di fare qualcosa intercettando un evento (click, mouseover, onclick..)
      mouseover: function(){//creo una function anonima
        console.log("MOUSE OVER");
      }, //sotto scrivo un'altra funzione sempre ANONIMA

      click: function(){//tutte le volte che scrivo "nome-evento" e due punti dentro gli passo un oggetto
        console.log("CLICK"); 

      }

    }); 

  $("#nascondi-immagine")
    .on({
      click:function(){//quando faccio click
        $("img").hide();//devi nascondere l'immagine 
      }
    });

  $("#mostra-immagine")
    .on({
      click:function(){
        $("img").fadeIn(3000);//immagine deve comparire in 3'
      }
    });

  //prEventDefault serve a prevenire il comportamento di default del dom html
  $("#effetti a")//sul DIV che si chiama effetti SELEZIONO gli elementi a
    .on({ //permette di fare qualcosa intercettando un evento (click, mouseover, onclick..)
      click:function(e){//passo un parametro "e" che corrisponde all'elemento "a" in pratica
        e.preventDefault();
      }

    });


  $(window)
    .on("load", function(){
      $("#effetti")
        .css({
          "margin-top":10%
        });
    });

    $(window)//l'oggetto window di js
      .on("load",function(){//scrivo load ed apro un function anonima
        $("#sposta-immagine")
          .on({
            click:function(){//al compimento di questa azione ovvero click su bottone
              $("effetti")//sul DIV che si chiama effetti
                .css({
                  "background":"red",
                  "margin-left":10%
                });
            }
          });
      });

});
```

when I update the 1.js file even if I delete the function from line 50-62 it continues to give me the usual error. in the sense the google chrome console always gives me the old error on that code even if that code has been deleted

Comment: Your `</head>` closing tag is missing. You can use this https://jsfiddle.net/ check the color of your tag or syntax. If there's an error your code will be highlighted.

Comment: The `10% }` in `"margin-top":10% }` is not a valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the mistake I found**

```
$(window)//l'oggetto window di js
      .on("load",function(){//scrivo load ed apro un function anonima
        $("#sposta-immagine")
          .on({
            click:function(){//al compimento di questa azione ovvero click su bottone
              $("effetti")//sul DIV che si chiama effetti
                .css({
                  "background":"red",
                  "margin-left":10%
                });
            }
          });
      });
```

1. `$("effetti")` selecter is not correct `$("#effetti")`
2. `"background"` I think, would be `"background-color"
3. `10%` should be marked as string `"10%"`.
4. You can use single $(window).on("load", function() { ... }); to wrap multiple code context. just for the best practice.

Here is the fixed code:

```
$(function() {

 $("#effetti")
        .fadeIn(12000); //effetto opacita in 12 secondi 

    $("#effetti") //sul DIV che si chiama effetti
        .on({ //permette di fare qualcosa intercettando un evento (click, mouseover, onclick..)
            mouseover: function() { //creo una function anonima
                console.log("MOUSE OVER");
            }, //sotto scrivo un'altra funzione sempre ANONIMA

            click: function() { //tutte le volte che scrivo "nome-evento" e due punti dentro gli passo un oggetto
                console.log("CLICK");

            }

        });

    $("#nascondi-immagine")
        .on({
            click: function() { //quando faccio click
                $("img").hide(); //devi nascondere l'immagine 
            }
        });

    $("#mostra-immagine")
        .on({
            click: function() {
                $("img").fadeIn(3000); //immagine deve comparire in 3'
            }
        });

    //prEventDefault serve a prevenire il comportamento di default del dom html
    $("#effetti a") //sul DIV che si chiama effetti SELEZIONO gli elementi a
        .on({ //permette di fare qualcosa intercettando un evento (click, mouseover, onclick..)
            click: function(e) { //passo un parametro "e" che corrisponde all'elemento "a" in pratica
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        });


    $(window)
        .on("load", function() {
            $("#effetti")
                .css({
                    "margin-top": "10px"
                });


            $("#sposta-immagine").on("click", function() { //al compimento di questa azione ovvero click su bottone
                $("#effetti") //sul DIV che si chiama effetti
                    .css({ "background-color": "red", "margin-left": "10px" });
            });

        });
});
```

Find the working example here.

https://playcode.io/325382?tabs=console&index.html&output

Comment: thank you very much, the only thing that does not work as I would like is the function on line 50-62. if clicked on "SPOSTA" does not work. in short, the css background rules are not applied ":" red "," margin-left ":" 10% "on the button

Comment: @t.niese the question context was not improving the code or providing the solutions for pixel... the user was having some code-mistake (syntax related issue). If it need improvements you can comment as suggestion instead of downvote the solution.

Comment: @GianmarcoGagliardi try the solution now. I have updated the fix for that.

Comment: it works you solved my problem. thank you so much

Comment: @t.niese here the User having much more syntax related issue in code that needs to be improved. You can either update the solutions with suggested edits :) Always downvote a solutions is not a good practice.

Comment: You are welcome @GianmarcoGagliardi can you please mark solution as accepted.

Comment: some things I didn't check out in your solution: $("#sposta-immagine").on("click", function() { 
                $("#effetti") 
                    .css({ "background-color": "red", "margin-left": "10px" });
            });
because the windows object disappeared and because the windows object disappeared and on.click: ?

Comment: @GianmarcoGagliardi sorry didn't get you `some things I didn't check out in your solution:`

Comment: @GianmarcoGagliardi I have updated the solution with what edit required. Please confirm now.

Comment: `Here is the mistake I found` does this helpful?

Comment: @GianmarcoGagliardi if you see the solution carefully the `$(window)
        .on("load", function() {` is there... just removed the duplicated onload.. you can wrap as much as code in single window.onload block. No need to include window.onload for each conde context.

Comment: @GianmarcoGagliardi did you get your ans?

Comment: The answer now contains some of the necessary explanations. But why should `.on({ click: function(){` be invalid and be written as `$("#sposta-immagine").on("click", function() {` ?  Passing an object to `on` with the event name(s)  as property is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: OK thanks to all, I solved it like this:$(window)//l'oggetto window di js
      .on("load",function(){//scrivo load ed apro un function anonima
        $("#sposta-immagine")
          .on({
            click:function(){//al compimento di questa azione ovvero click su bottone
              $("#effetti")//sul DIV che si chiama effetti
                .css({
                  "background-color":"red",
                  "margin-left":"10%"
                });
            }
          });
      });

Comment: Cool @GianmarcoGagliardi it's my pleasure to get your problem resolved. Please mark solution as accepted.

Comment: Also a great help from @t.niese can't ignored. Thanks :+1

Comment: @GianmarcoGagliardi please mark this if it helps to prepare your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript (and most other languages) `10%` does not mean 10 percent.

It is the beginning of an expression ([Arithmetic operators: Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())) and expects an operand after `%`, but in your code it is followed by a `}` (`"margin-top":10% }`) and that's a syntax error.

The value has to be encapsulated into a string `'10%'`.

And as of that it has to be:

```
$("#effetti")
  .css({
    "margin-top": "10%"
  });
```

and (with corrected selector `effetti` has to be `#effetti`)

```
$("#effetti") //sul DIV che si chiama effetti
  .css({
    "background": "red",
    "margin-left": "10%"
  });
```

Comment: Solution should resolve the user problem...Complete solution would always welcome. try jsfiddle or any other tools to provide/add your explanatery example.  here I can see the selector is not correct and `background` should be `background-color` as question prospective.

Comment: @VikashPathakt the question is about the syntax error nothing else. StackOverflow is a Q&A platform that is about specific problems (where you should ask one question at a time). It is great to solve other problems too, in addition to the one that is asked, but that's not the point of the Q&A platform.

Comment: @VikashPathak `"background": "red"` is perfectly valid.

Comment: let's close the debate... I leaned few new things today. Thanks!

Comment: As we could able to help User that is the most important thing. :+1